# First-order logic: where's the the flaw in this argument?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

There must be a flaw in the following argument, but I don't see it at the moment.  Who can point it out?

In first-order logic, suppose that a structure $\mathfrak{U}$ is a model of the formula ($x = 3$):

$$ \mathfrak{U} \vDash x = 3 $$

Then, by the definition of a model, for any assignment function s it is true that

$$ \mathfrak{U} \vDash (x = 3) [s]$$

So the universe of $\mathfrak{U}$ has only one element, which equals the constant 3.  And so the structure is also a model of $\forall x (x = 3)$:

$$ \mathfrak{U} \vDash \forall x (x = 3) $$

We have just seen that any model of $x = 3$ is also a model of $\forall x (x = 3)$.  So

$$ x = 3 \vDash \forall x (x = 3) $$

Choose any complete deduction system for first-order logic.  Then by completeness we have

$$ x = 3 \vdash \forall x (x = 3) $$

There is a natural deduction rule

$$ \frac{\Gamma, A \vdash B}{\Gamma \vdash A \to B} $$

So we can apply it to obtain

$$ \varnothing \vdash x = 3 \to \forall x (x = 3) $$

or

$$ \vdash x = 3 \to \forall x (x = 3) $$

But that statement seems to be invalid.  For example, it's not true in a structure whose universe has more than one element under an assignment that maps x to 3.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Since it otherwise contains an unbound variable, isn't $x = 3$ implicitly $\forall x(x =3)$?

Comment: The flaw is, unsurprisingly, when you say "presumably it is true...".

Comment: Should be $\exists x (x=3)$

Comment: Depending on the particular formulation of first logic, the exact error you have may vary, however the one I know best is the version in which the Deduction Theorem ("natural deduction rule") requires that in the proof to which you apply the theorem, you don't use Generalization on on a variable free in the hypothesis. Semantically, your last formula is not logically valid, but the second formula IS correct since: if the formula $x=3$ is TRUE (not just satisfied) in some structure, then it's generalization is also true in that structure ("true" means satisfied by all assignments).

Comment: @AlexKruckman: I edited my question to make my argument more precise, and removed the dodgy-sounding text "Presumably it is true".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, $ x = 3 \models (\forall x \mathop. x = 3)$ is not true, and it is not true for the following reason.

$ \Phi \models \Delta $, where $\Phi$ and $\Delta$ are sets of formulas, means the following:

$$\Phi \models \Delta \;\; \textit{if and only if} \;\; \text{for all $(M, v)$, if $M, v \models \Phi$, then $M, v \models \Delta$} $$

$M, v \models \varphi$ means that $\varphi$ holds in the structure $M$ with the *variables interpreted by $v$, a mapping from variable names to their denotations*. Note that we are quantifying over $M$ and $v$ at the same time.

The relation that you appear to be using in place of $\models$ is well-defined, and we might write it $\Phi \models^g \Delta$. I have seen it called the *global consequence relation* of first-order logic, but it is not commonly used and certainly isn't the default. *I'm only mentioning the global consequence relation at all to stress the importance of running back to the definitions in logic.* I first heard about the idea of a global consequence relation from [sequitur's answer to a question I asked about modal logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4226163).

$$ \Phi \models^g \Delta \;\;\textit{if and only if}\;\; \text{for all $M$ such that $M \models \Phi$, it holds that $M \models \Delta$} $$

In the above definition $M \models \Phi$ holds if and only if $M, v \models \Phi$ for all $v$.

In the family of proof systems that use the $\vdash$ notation, $\vdash$ is the syntactic analogue of $\models$ not $\models^g$.

Also, as you have noticed, it is indeed not true that $x = 3 \models^g (\forall x \mathop. x = 3)$ implies $\models^g (x = 3) \to (\forall x \mathop. x = 3)$.

The equivalent of implication introduction in some hypothetical proof system in $\models^g$-land would give us $\models^g (\forall x \mathop. x = 3) \to (\forall x \mathop. x = 3)$. Basically, because the free variables are quantified over *early*, we have to protect statements that contain them.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful reply!  I got the definition of ⊨ that I was using from the textbook "A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic, 2nd Edition" by Christopher Leary (https://tinyurl.com/friendlylogic).  In section 1.9 "Logical Implication", it says "Definition 1.9.1. Suppose that ∆ and Γ are sets of L-formulas. We will say that ∆ logically implies Γ and write ∆ |= Γ if for every L-structure U, if U |= ∆, then U |= Γ."  I had no idea that this definition was not standard!  I just checked Enderton's "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic" and saw that his definition agrees with yours.

Comment: @AdamDingle I briefly checked the book you linked and they are indeed not constraining $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ to be sets of sentences. Their choice of definition of $\models$ appears to be consistent with the proof calculus they're using, which looks like a Hilbert system (in section 2.4). This sort of makes sense, we want $\vdash$ and $\models$ to "line up" because of the completeness theorem. My calling $\models^g$ nonstandard may have been too strong. I don't actually know how widespread it is. I just know that I haven't come across a book yet which explicitly covers both relations.

Comment: The global consequence relation was used in many mathematical logic textbooks (without the little "g" notation) as the primary notion of logical consequence [Mendelson's text for example]. However, I've been away from this stuff for a long while so I don't know what's found in newer treatments.

Comment: As a followup (over a year later), I just noticed that in Rautenberg's textbook "A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic, 3rd Edition" he discusses the relationship between ⊨ and ⊨g on pp. 80-81 in section 2.5 "Logical Consequence and Theories".  I found his explanation to be helpful.