# Prove if $\Box \Box p \to \Box p$ is valid on Frame $F=\langle W,R \rangle$ then $R$ is dense

Tags: modal-logic

Prove if $\Box \Box p \to \Box p$ is valid on Frame $F=\langle W,R \rangle$ then $R$ is dense.

Where dense means $\forall  w,v \in W: wRv \implies \exists u \in W : wRu\ \&\ uRv$.

I know we are supposed to come up with a valuation such that when $wRv$ and $M,w \models \Box \Box p \to \Box p$ we must have the denese-ness property but I'm not sure where to even begin since $\Box\Box p$ requires length 2 path.

Comment: Did you notice that the definition of "dense" also requires a length $2$ path, $wRu\ \&\ uRv$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to be careful about what things we're quantifying over at what time when dealing with modal logic. Sequitur answered [a question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4483219) eight months ago that gives  the standard names for the different parts of a modal model.

I interpret $\square\square p \to \square p$ holds on the frame to mean:

> For all models $M$ with frame $\langle W, R \rangle$ and all worlds $w$, it holds for all propositions $p$ that $M, w \models \square \square p \to \square p$

In particular, a frame $\langle W, R \rangle$ does *not* include a valuation, which means we get to pick our valuations in very obnoxious ways to rule out features of the accessibility relation that we don't like.

First, let's note that $\square \square p \to \square p$ enforces the same conditions as $\lozenge p \to \lozenge\lozenge p$.

Proof:

- $\square\square p \to \square p \;\;\;\;$ is our hypothesis.
- $\square\square \lnot \lnot p \to \square \lnot \lnot p \;\;\;\;$ holds by double negation introduction.
- $\lnot \lozenge \lozenge \lnot p \to \lnot \lozenge \lnot p \;\;\;\;$ holds since $\square$ and $\lozenge$ are dual.
- $\lozenge \lnot p \to \lozenge \lozenge \lnot p \;\;\;\;$ holds by contrapositive elimination.

And note that $\lozenge p \to \lozenge \lozenge p$ enforces the same frame condition since $p$ is universally quantified, so we can add or remove $\lnot$ as long as we do it uniformly.

With that out of the way, let's pick two not necessarily distinct worlds, $u$ and $v$, such that $uRv$.

World $u$ is our starting point.

Pick a variable, let's say $a$ and declare $a$ to be true at world $v$ and false everywhere else.

$M, u \models \lozenge a$ is true, since we can get from $u$ to $v$, the only world where $a$ holds.

Therefore, $M, u \models \lozenge \lozenge a$ must also be true, i.e. there must exist an intermediate world $w$ such that $uRw$ and $wRv$. This is the only way to satisfy $\lozenge \lozenge a$, since $a$ is false everywhere except at world $v$.

Therefore $R$ is dense.

Comment: I think i understand everything except how  $\Diamond \neg p \to \Diamond\Diamond \neg p$ implies $\Diamond p \to \Diamond\Diamond p$

Comment: @CHTM $\lozenge p \to \lozenge \lozenge p$ is not a logical consequence. What I’m saying is $p$ ranges over all propositions and $\lnot$ is an involution on propositions, so uniformly replacing $p$ with $\lnot p$ yields an equivalent frame condition.